# Can't run Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 Radeon

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, steam, radeon, opengl

I installed Steam using the deb package on the website, but it kept giving me this error:

Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Then, I installed it with Wine, but it can't install games because of some network error.

Then, I tried installing it how everyone on YouTube says and I couldn't start it.